# Uploading Document in Chunks on SharePoint using Web Services with some MetaData

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to Upload large file on Sharepoint.So i am uploading it in chunks.
But i am unable to give meta information at the time of Uploading file.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the little known RPC way, check http://vspug.com/smc750/2009/05/19/uploading-content-into-sharepoint-let-me-count-the-ways/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  You have to upload the document and set metadata via 2 separate web service calls.  One solution would be to write your own web service that does both in 1 step, assuming you have access to deploy server side applications on your sharepoint box.

Answer (score 0):

unzip the file and only pass the XML which you want... with a 2007 doc, rename it to a zip file, then open the zip and you will see all the XML.